# What to do with the questions of the new users who don't use the searcher?

Tags: discussion

I'm every day here looking for new questions, and trying to learn more about Ethereum and the blockchain, but since 2 months ago i only see the same qeustions of a new users like

> "how many time take to finish a transaction", "why this faucet is not
>   working?" , "How i can send ether?".

These questions are already answered in others 5 or 10 similar questions... Directly or indirectly. What we can do with this? spam of  duplicated flags? downvotes? What is the best way?

This is one example of what i mean: 
[Deploy contract from command line](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/20998/deploy-contract-from-command-line)

This question is easy solved whit searching "Deploy contract" in the searcher, but is common for new users do spam with this questions.

Comment: Flag as duplicate, once *x* votes have been received on the question, or someone with the reputation to, the question will be closed and marked as a duplicate with a link to the other question.

Comment: Yes but this for all questions? And if you don't are sure if is a really duplicate you can flag as duplicate anyway? And the most important problem, in other site bigger than this is easy to flag and close a question but here with luck the question can obtain 5  or less flags in one week...

Comment: Flagging as duplicate seems the standard way to deal with this. In addition to flagging, if it's obvious that the user is a first-timer, a comment (like "please use the search functionality next time") would help them in either learning the correct way or explaining why (if) the question was not a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

Flag as duplicate is the best choice we have here. Also leave a message for the OP.